# What are the cycles in this graph, and what are their sizes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have the following graph $G$. I'd like to find how many cycles there are and what their sizes are.

[image]

Please correct me if I am wrong: in this graph there are $2$ cycles, $\text{1-2-3-4-5-1}$ with size $5$, and the other $\text{4-5-4}$ with size $2$.

Is that true? As mentioned in a theorem:

> If $G$ is simple and deg$^+(v)\geq k\geq 1$, then there is a simple cycle of at least size $k+1$ ...
>   where $deg^+(v)$  is  the out-degree of v.
>   I did not find $(k+1)$ here?

how can I choose value of k in the second Graph:

[image: Gaph2]

Comment: What is $\operatorname{deg}+(v)$?

Comment: @angryavian: Probably $\deg^+(v)$, the out-degree of $v$.

Comment: Yes 
updated it , thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hypothesis of the theorem should be that $\deg^+(v)\ge k\ge 1$ for all nodes $v$ of the graph. In your graph nodes $1,2,3$, and $4$ have out-degree $1$, and node $5$ has out-degree $2$, so we must choose $k=1$. The theorem then guarantees that there is a cycle of length at least $2$, which is true: as you point out, there are two of them, one of length exactly $2$ and one of length $5$.

Note that the theorem does not guarantee a cycle of length exactly $k+1$, though in this case there is one; it just says that there is a cycle whose length is $\ge k+1$.

Comment: How about the second Graph? what is k and why ?

Comment: @Tandee: Since there are vertices with out-degree $1$, the only possible choice for $k$ is $1$. In general $k$ will be the minimum out-degree of any vertex, assuming that each vertex has out-degree at least $1$.

Comment: since k =1 the minimum out-degree, so what is the size of the cycle: Here  both are $>$ than k+1 which is $>$ 1+1

Comment: @Tandee: Yes, here you have cycles of length $4$ and $5$. That’s fine: the theorem just says that there must be a cycle of length **at least** $k+1=2$, and $4$ and $5$ are certainly at least $2$.

Comment: Oh, so you mean at least 2 but we have got 4 and it is still greater than 2 :(k+1)

Comment: @Tandee: $4\ge 2$, so $4$ is at least $2$: *at least* $x$ simply means $\ge x$.